# Regex match string in double or single quote and follow by space

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match string which can be between single or double quote and must follow with a specific text.

`input`:

```
<title ng-bind="'key_name' | i18n"></title>
```

or can be

```
<span class="sr-only">{{ 'key_name' | i18n }}</span>
```

or

```
<span class="sr-only">{{ "key_name" | i18n }}</span>
```

I want to capture that `key_name`

This is what I have so far but failed.

```
["']([^)]+)["']\s|\si18n
```

Comment: How about [`(?:'([^']*?)'|"([^"]*?)")\s\|\si18n`](http://regex101.com/r/pI3hC9)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should work for you:

```
["']([^"']+?)['"]\s*\|\s*i18n
```

Check here:

http://regex101.com/r/aI1lX4

Comment: @Ali I was updating it while you left the comment. Check the new regex. It will give you `_add_an_event_`, `_need_to_login_` and `_add_events_`

Comment: I was basically tweaking it to make it non-greedy and also to remove the quotes from the captured group.

Comment: Just FYI, changing the plus signs to asterisks doesn't make the regex less greedy, but it does make it more robust.  Maybe the OP knows there will always be exactly one space in each of those spots, but it's best to assume whitespace is not significant until/unless the OP says otherwise.

Comment: @AlanMoore I agree. When I said *to make it non-greedy*, I was referring to an edit that isn't reflected in the Revisions :) The one you see is to do exactly what you're saying: Allow something like `'key_name'|i18n` which is perfectly valid in Django's templates (or a similar templating system).

Answer (score 1):

This expression will work for the three examples you posted, but it is altogether not very flexible.

```
/(?:\{\{\s*|"\s*(?=')|'\s*(?="))((['"]).*?\2)\s\|\si18n/
// Without capturing quotes:
/(?:\{\{\s*|"\s*(?=')|'\s*(?="))(['"])(.*)?\1\s\|\si18n/
```

The actual match will be in `[1]` and `[2]`, respectively.  You may want to change some of the `\s` to `\s*` or `\s+`.

Comment: It even captured the single quote?

Comment: @Ali was it not supposed to?

Comment: I thought it should just return the key name without the quote?

Comment: @Ali I updated my answer to include a version that excludes the quotes from what is captured

Answer (score 0):

```
.*(["'])([^)]*?)\1\s*?\|\s*?i18n
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/x8OOoE1Aru3HJg5f)

".*" in the beginning is required to match the least number of characters as possible. Backreference to the first capture is to ensure that both quotes match. Any number of whitespace is permissible around the "|". This is assuming no unescaped quote marks are within the text you want to capture, though. The match result is in $2, as $1 is used to maintain the quote marks.

Comment: `.*` isn't *required* to match anything, but it *wants* to match everything.  By adding it you've created a regex that matches everything from the beginning of the string to the last instance of `'key_name' | i18n`,  and I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Is the substring in the quotes always a single word, like `key_name`?  If so, this should be all you need:

```
(["'])(\w+)\1\s*\|\s*i18n\b
```

If not, this might set you right:

```
(["'])([^'"]+)\1\s*\|\s*i18n\b
```

In either case, the part you're looking for will be captured in group #2.  If your needs are more complicated than this, we'll need more info.